# body-parser doesn't populate req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm using express 4.14 and body-parser module.
req.body obj is not getting populated. The order of binding is proper as pointed out in answers for similar questions.

***app.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var engine = require('ejs-locals');

var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs',engine);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/authme', index);

module.exports = app;
```

***index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/authme',function(req,res,next){
        console.log(req.body);
        var userIdEntered = req.param("useridip2");

});
module.exports = router;
```

req.body is empty.

Comment: There is no `body` for GET request.

Comment: And keep in mind that the `next` param is only needed in middlewares.